# How to get user id which is done by buddypress

Tags: buddypress, user-registration

I have integrated buddypress in my wordpress theme. i need to get user id when buddypress completes user registration successfully like what we usually do wp_insert_user( $userdata ) which returns user id when user information is successfully inserted..so how do i get user id?

its urgent..pleas help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

if you put this action you will get the new user_id that wordpress provide when new user register

```
add_action("bp_core_activated_user","bp_autologin_on_activation",40,3);
function bp_autologin_on_activation($user_id,$key,$user) {

...

}
```

I hope help